# Make it more obvious that commenting is only possible after earning certain reputation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, feedback

The comment link should be always visible. For users without enough rep to comment, clicking on it should give a nice popup, just like those on the vote buttons, informing them that they need more reputation to comment.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that will generate a different frustration: Folks will complain about why they're encouraged to "comment" if they're not allowed to yet.

But I agree with the sentiment - in a more "button-based" app, I'd think what you'd want is the equivalent of a "grayed-out" button in a GUI, possibly with a hovertip telling you how much rep you need.  Would that work in a "link-based" app?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that users with 1 reputation can comment on their own questions, answers, and any answers to their questions.

In fact, we pre-expand the comments on questions asked by new users to ENCOURAGE them to use comments.

Answer (score 2):

For some time now (few years, can't say when exactly is was done) the "add comment" link  is indeed always visible, and when clicked by a user without enough reputation, showing such a message:

> [image]